# The difference between two assert expressions?

Tags: java, assert

what is the difference between the 2 cases at runtime execution ?

```
private void doStuff() {
assert (y > x);
// more code assuming y is greater than x
}

private void doStuff() {
assert (y > x): "y is " + y + " x is " + x;
// more code assuming y is greater than x
}
```

Comment: Um, what language is that?

Comment: this is java langauage

Comment: One of the `assert` statements just overrides the `AssertionError` error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `assert` statement takes the following form

```
assert Expression1 : Expression2 ;
```

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.10) states

> Otherwise, execution continues by making a choice based on the value
>   of `Expression1`:
>
> - If the value is true, no further action is taken and the assert
>     statement completes normally.
> - **If the value is false, the execution behavior depends on whether
>     `Expression2` is present:**
>
>   - **If `Expression2` is present, it is evaluated.**
>
>     - If the evaluation completes abruptly for some reason, the assert
>         statement completes abruptly for the same reason.
>     - **If the evaluation completes normally, an AssertionError instance whose
>         "detail message" is the resulting value of Expression2 is created.**
>
>       - If the instance creation completes abruptly for some reason, the
>           assert statement completes abruptly for the same reason.
>       - If the instance creation completes normally, the assert statement
>           completes abruptly by throwing the newly created `AssertionError`
>           object.
>   - **If `Expression2` is not present, an `AssertionError` instance with no
>       "detail message" is created.**